# Keeping a marker centered even during map move

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I need to keep the marker centered all the time, even during drag and pan of the map and update its LngLat according to the map movement.

While most of it works, but I just can't figure out how to keep the marker cenrtered *during* the map drag/pan.

Here's what I have so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/yLf4wgzd/1/

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
});
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([0, 0])
    .addTo(map);

map.on('movestart', function (e) {
    console.log(`Current Map Center: ${map.getCenter()}`);
    marker.setLngLat(map.getCenter());
});
map.on('moveend', function (e) {
    console.log(`Current Map Center: ${map.getCenter()}`);
    marker.setLngLat(map.getCenter());
});
```

One way I can think of is to poll `map.isMoving` every few milliseconds and update the markers location but that doesn't seem an optimal solution.

Comment: On `movestart` you could start polling your `map.isMoving` and then stop it on `moveend` , you only poll it while the map is moving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`move`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:move) event of the map to update the position of the marker while the map is moving. Here is [your example](https://jsfiddle.net/w4t8snv7/6/) updated.